# Updating a D3 pie chart correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have a pie chart that takes data from an array of numbers. These numbers are changed dynamically based on some controls that the user has. In any case, I've created a second array `data2` alongside `data`.

I've tried working through a few solutions: using arcTween or simply just utilizing what I know about updating bar graphs; however, it seems that the pie chart functions differently compared to the bar graphs which I have been able to update.

Here is the [CodePen link](http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/xqELZG?editors=1010) as well.

In any case here is the structure of my pie chart:

```
var color = ["red","blue","green","orange"];
var data = [10,12,15,17];
var data2 = [21,22,14,12];
var dataKey = ["Employed","Student","Unemployed","Retired"];
var radius = 200;
var canvas = d3.select("#general_graph").append("svg")
  .attr("width",400)
  .attr("height",400);

var group = canvas.append("g")
  .attr("transform","translate(200,200)");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(120)
  .outerRadius(radius);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function(d){return d;});

var arcs = group.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class","arc");

arcs.append("path")
  .attr("d",arc)
  .attr("fill",function(d,i){return color[i];});

var text = arcs.append("text")
  .attr("transform",function(d){return "translate("+arc.centroid(d)+")";})
  .attr("text-anchor","middle")
  .attr("font-size","1.5em")
  .attr("fill","#fff")
  .attr("font-family","Franklin Gothic")
  .text(function(d){ return Math.round(d.data); });
```

This works as expected but trying to find an example chart that utilizes the same way I set up my pie chart has been seemingly impossible. Here is what I have down at the moment in terms of upgrading:

```
document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 17)
    {
      /*
      arcs.data(pie(data2));
      canvas.selectAll("path")
        .attr("d",arc)
        .attr("fill",function(d,i){return color[i];}); */

      update();


      /*
      text
        .data(pie)
        .transition().duration(750)
        .attr("transform",function(d){return "translate("+arc.centroid(d)+")";})
        .text(function(d){ return Math.round(d.data); }); */
    }
}

function arcTween(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}

function update(){
  var path = group.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie(d2_data2))
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color[i]; })
    .transition()
    .delay(function(d, i) {
      return i * 800;
    })
    .attrTween('d', function(d) {
     var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle+0.1, d.endAngle);
     return function(t) {
         d.endAngle = i(t);
       return arc(d);
     }
    });
}
```

As you can see the chart should upgrade when the "CTRL" key is press; however, due to my misunderstanding of how pie chart updates function, it does not.

Again, here is the link to the [CodePen posts.](http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/xqELZG?editors=1010)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Working codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWbMGP?editors=1010

Your problem is not with the piechart, but with D3's data join.

First of all you have a typo with your second data array `.data(pie(d2_data2))` should be `.data(pie(data2))`

You have to be mindful of how D3 decides what data is `enter` or `update` Both `data` and `data2` have the same length, so when you give D3 `data2` it sees it as an update rather than an enter.

I've generalized your code so that you just need to pass your desired array to `update()` and it should work.